# I am trying to scrape a website using Scrapy. It gets access to robots.txt file with "status code 200" but " 555" on terminal

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to scrape a real estate website . It shows status code 200 but in terminal it shows 555.
how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

go in your settings.py file and add in comment this
**ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True** ==> **# ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True**